# vglm: how to loop with variables strings in model?

Tags: r, loops, glm, logistic-regression

I've [found](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/pages/looping_strings.htm) a handy solution in order code a loop calling vglm() **but only with a single variable**:

```
R: varlist
[1] "X2"  "X7"  "X17" "X18" "X33"
models <- lapply(varlist, function(x) {
  vglm(substitute(class ~ i, list(i = as.name(x))), data = train.data[c(-1)], family = multinomial())
})
```

Since I want to perform variable selection with AIC, I run the following

```
resAIC = lapply(models, AIC)
R: resAIC
[[1]]
[1] 11918.26

[[2]]
[1] 11917.55

[[3]]
[1] 11919.45

[[4]]
[1] 11926.03

[[5]]
[1] 11923.2
```

Now, for the next vglm call I have to update variable list for AIC, it's now:

```
R: varlist
[1] "X18+X2"  "X18+X7"  "X18+X17" "X18+X33"
```

And I get the following error when calling `models <- lapply(varlist, function(x) { vglm(...)})` again.

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'X18+X2' not found
Called from: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
```

How should I modify the code in order to be more general and accept "X2", "X18 + X2", "X18 + X2 + X33", etc. when calling vglm() respectively.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This does not answer your question but you might want to have a look at the stepAIC function from the caret package. It might make your life easier.

Comment: Thanks, haven't heard of caret, will check it out too. Note: I know the stepAIC from MASS package though, but it needs a glm model, and glm doesn't work on my (very) sparse matrix.

Comment: Yeah my bad, that's it from the MASS package. Great then the answer is helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than messing around with building a formula dynamically, i might suggest subsetting the columns of your data.frame and not bothering with building strings with pluses.

```
#SAMPLE DATA
train.data<-data.frame(class=sample(1:5, 50, replace=T), 
    matrix(runif(50*12), ncol=12))

library(VGAM)
varlist <- list("X2", c("X8","X2"), c("X8","X2","X11"))
models <- lapply(varlist, function(x) {
    vglm(class ~ ., data = train.data[, c("class", x)], family = multinomial())
})
```

You can extrtact the AIC and terms with

```
sapply(models, AIC)
sapply(models, function(x) attr(terms(x), "term.labels"))
```